# Проблема с подключением к SQL Server в Flutter

Tags: sql, sql-server, flutter

Как подключиться к SQL Server в Flutter используя `SqlConnection`?
Вот-так выглядела строка подключения к базе данных в c#

```cs
Data Source=BCAD09H\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyBase;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; Application Name = EntityFramework
```

Вот-так пробовал

```dart
SQLConnection con = SqlConnection(host: "BCAD09H\\SQLEXPRESS", db: "MyBase");
```

Comment: **1) This package is not suitable for flutter or web projects. It only runs on server-side apps. 2) It works only on Windows (32bits or 64bits)**

Comment: @MiT А что луше всего использовать для подключения к Sql Server?

Comment: REST API, GraphQL...

Comment: @MiT А есть какая-то библиотека для подключения к локальному серверу?

Comment: Нет ничего, так как Sql Server это БД для back-end.

Comment: @MiT А если разместить базу на удаленном сервере то как к ней подключиться?

Comment: REST API, GraphQL... Поймите, напрямую к БД клиент не должен подключаться... Только через back-end.

Comment: @MiT Я так понял что только через HTTP?

Comment: `Integrated Security=True` - подозреваю, что надо перенастраивать sql server.

Comment: И вообще, из приложения давать доступ к базе - так себе идея, так что переделать всё.